# Limiting hexadecimal length with gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to convert a negative decimal to a hexadecimal with max length of 8 using gawk, like this:

```
echo -1 | awk '{printf "%08X\n", $1}'
```

In a HP-UX 11.31 machine, this gives me:

```
FFFFFFFF
```

In a Linux machine, with gawk, this gives me:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Is there any way to limit the length of the result with gawk?

Thanks.

Comment: That's the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit computing.  You could get the 32-bit result with `{printf "%08X", $1 & 0xFFFFFFFF}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use sprintf and then check the length of the string it returns.

```
res = sprintf("%08X", $1)
if (length(res) > 8) {
    ...
}
```